# HTTP proxy Configuration always returns error 403 on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, proxy, ubuntu-16.04

After Installing Jenkins on Ubuntu, I get screen where it shows that jenkins is working in offline mode. It gives option to configure proxy, even after entering correct proxy details for server name, port, username and password I get error message "Failed to connect to http://jenkins-ci.org/ (code 403)", when trying to validate proxy. Have entered many other url but each gives same error.

Also, the same url gives result on wget on server(ubuntu) hosting jenkins.
Have also set proxy for JENKINS user on host machine

Answer (score 0):

In proxy, provide only proxy host and port. Leave the username and password empty And go to .jenkins folder and update the URL from https to Http in the hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml file. Restart and try again with proxy.